# Connecting to Azure SQL with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to a SQL Database hosted in Windows Azure through MySQLdb with Python.

I keep getting an error mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2001, 'Bad connection string.')

This information works when connecting through .NET (vb, C#) but I am definitely not having any luck here.

For  below I used my server's name from azure then .database.windows.net   Is this the correct way to go about this?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="<servername>.database.windows.net", user="myUsername", passwd="myPassword", db="db_name")

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I have also tried using pyodbc with FreeTDS with no luck.

Comment: Can you please try by adding server name to your user name? Something like: `user="myUsername@<servername>"`.

Comment: I've added `user="myUsername@<servername>" ` Now it's saying mysql_exception.OperationalError: (2002, 'Internal error.')

Comment: Can you try connecting via `pymssql`? All the examples I have seen makes use of this.

Comment: Using pymssql connection string looks like `conn = pymssql.conect(host="<servername>.database.windows.net", user="myUsername", password="myPassword", database="db_name")  ` I get "Operation now in progressDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9: Adaptive Server connection failed

Comment: `mysqldb` is an interface to MySQL. Azure's SQL Database Service is a SQL Server variant, not a MySQL variant. You need to choose a library that works with SQL Server, not MySQL. And which you choose (such as the one Gaurav suggested) is up to you. Also: if you're going to change library, *edit your question* - don't put additional detail as comments. Very hard to read, very hard to get the new context of your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Kyle Moffat, what OS are you on? Here is how you can use pyodbc on Linux and Windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763261(v=sql.1).aspx

**Windows:**

- Download and install Python
- Install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13:

  - v13: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420
  - v11: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434
- Open cmd.exe as an administrator
- Install pyodbc using pip - Python package manager

  ```
  cd C:\Python27\Scripts>  
  pip install pyodbc
  ```

**Linux:**

- Open terminal
  Install Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for Linux For Ubuntu 15.04 +

  ```
   sudo su  
   wget https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ODBC-Driver-13-for-Ubuntu-b87369f0/file/154097/2/installodbc.sh  
   sh installodbc.sh
  ```
- For RedHat 6,7

  ```
  sudo su
  wget https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ODBC-Driver-13-for-SQL-8d067754/file/153653/4/install.sh 
  sh install.sh
  ```
- Install pyodbc

  ```
  sudo -H pip install pyodbc
  ```

Once you install the ODBC driver and pyodbc you can use this Python sample to connect to Azure SQL DB

```
import pyodbc 
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print row[0] 
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

If you are not able to install the ODBC Driver you can also try pymssql + FreeTDS

```
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install freetds-dev freetds-bin
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install python-dev python-pip
sudo pip install pymssql==2.1.1
```

Once you follow these steps, you can use the following code sample to connect:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715796(v=sql.1).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I am getting a Driver Manager error but the so called missing file is where it is looking? I am currently on a rpi model B `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./connect.py", line 8, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';password='+password)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`
Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? Did you run the following?  `sudo su
wget https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ODBC-Driver-13-for-Ubuntu-b87369f0/file/154097/2/installodbc.sh sh installodbc.sh`

Comment: I have ran this yes, it installed without a hitch.  I built the `.conf` file for `ibmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0` and added it to `/usr/lib`. I've updated the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and ran `sudo ldconfig` I am still getting the same error though! Is there a different solution to registering the `.so` file or a different way to link these files?

Comment: Kyle, what version of ODBC are you running? Can you go to /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/ and run `ldd libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0`

Comment: When I run ldd on the file it replies: "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Seems like something went wrong when installing the ODBC Driver. Can you try this on a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 or 16.04?

Comment: Hi, I apologize I haven't posted back.  I plugged in a fresh os Raspian Jessie (Full Desktop Image based on Debian Jessie) I have re-installed everything and am still getting the same error messages... I am still unable to successfully run ldd on `libmsodbcdsql-13.0.so.0.0`. I'm not really sure what to do at this point as myself not being able to figure this out has put me very behind schedule.  Is there another approach one would recommend to update a database while I sort this Python connection out when more time can be spared?

Comment: Hi Kyle, what version of Ubuntu is your Raspian Jessie running? Can you send me an email at meetb@microsoft.com and we can setup some time where I can walk you through how to make this work and then post the resolution back on SO