# Connect to SQL 14 Azure db from Pyodbc if SQL Server is MS 2012

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Some contractors I work with set up an Azure SQL db, ms server version 14. Is it possible to still connect with pyodbc if my personal machine still has SQL v11? If not, is there another method to connect?

Most of my connections are with ms server v11, so I would like to avoid upgrading my ms server if at all possible. I only need to connect to their azure server for a single query. Tried a few variations on the normal connection (trusted_connection = no, etc.)

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@azure_server/db')
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, think this was buried in [Connecting to Azure SQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461850/connecting-to-azure-sql-with-python)

Install ODBC driver 13 FTW!